# Unexecpected H T_STRING

Tags: php, html, http

What is this unexpected T_STRING "h" on line 39?
I Don't see any problem in the code, why is the string "h"?
I Think Its due to the java script option for orientation in the code
which i set to "h" or horizontal

```
<?php
include "system.php";
$usersystem = $_SESSION['username'];
$passw = $_SESSION['password'];
$query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$usersystem' AND password = '$passw'";
$autoexec= $mysqli->query($query);
$earnings = $autoexec['earnings'];
$completed = $autoexec['completed'];
if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] !=1){
    header ('Location: index.php);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>The Highest Paying GPT Site in the Industry!</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="GPT, Surveys, free money, free cash, free stuff" />
<meta name="description" content="A New Innovative GPT Site" />
<link href="css/templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ddsmoothmenu.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ddsmoothmenu.js">

/***********************************************
* Smooth Navigational Menu- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

ddsmoothmenu.init({
    mainmenuid: "templatemo_menu", //menu DIV id
    orientation: 'h', //Horizontal or vertical menu: Set to "h" or "v"
    classname: 'ddsmoothmenu', //class added to menu's outer DIV
    //customtheme: ["#1c5a80", "#18374a"],
    contentsource: "markup" //"markup" or ["container_id", "path_to_menu_file"]
})

</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/jquery.dualSlider.0.2.css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.timers-1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dualSlider.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#carousel").dualSlider({
            auto:true,
            autoDelay: 6000,
            easingCarousel: "swing",
            easingDetails: "easeOutBack",
            durationCarousel: 1000,
            durationDetails: 600
        });

    });

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="templatemo_header_wrapper">
    <div id="templatemo_header">
        <div id="site_title"><a href="index.php" rel="nofollow">Great GPT Site</a></div>
        <div id="templatemo_menu" class="ddsmoothmenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php" class="selected">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="how.php">How?</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="register.php">Register</a>


                </li>
                <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br style="clear: left" />
        </div> <!-- end of templatemo_menu -->
    </div> <!-- END of templatemo_header -->
</div> <!-- END of templatemo_header_wrapper -->

<div id="templatemo_slider_wrapper">
    <div id="templatemo_slider">
    <div id="carousel">
      <div class="panel"><!-- /details_wrapper -->
          <p></p>
          <h6></h6>
          <p></p>
          <h2>Welcome To Your Account! <?php echo "$username" ?></h2>
          <h6><em> Statistics</h6>
          <br />
          <h6><em>Earnings: <?php echo "$earnings" ?><em></h6>
          <br />
          <h6><em>Completed Offers: <?php echo "$completed" ?></h6>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <h6><em>Next Payment: End of next Month </h6>
          <h6><em><a href=offers.php>Offers List</a></em></h6>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <h5></h5>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;  </p>
          <h6></h6>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <br />
          <h6><em></h6>
        <p> l</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
        <!-- /panel -->
      <h6> Welcome to <?php echo $title?> </h6>

            <div id="slider-image-frame">
                <div class="backgrounds">

                    <div class="item item_1">
                        <img src="images/slider/02.jpg" alt="Image 01" />
                    </div><!-- /item -->

                    <div class="item item_2">
                        <img src="images/slider/03.jpg" alt="Image 02" />
                    </div><!-- /item -->

                    <div class="item item_3">
                        <img src="images/slider/01.jpg" alt="Image 03" />
                    </div><!-- /item -->

                </div><!-- /backgrounds -->
            </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- END of templatemo_slider -->
</div> <!-- END of templatemo_slider_wrapper -->
<div id="templatemo_main">
  <div class="homepage_post col half float_l">
    <h2>Latest News Bulletin</h2>
    <div class="post_meta">By Mark | Feburary 2, 2014</div>
    <h6><img src="images/templatemo_image_02.jpg" class="image_fl imgage-with-frame" alt="Image 02"/> </h6>
    <h6><em>New Offer Wall Added</em></h6>
    <h6>New Offer Wall By BLVD Media has been released, check it out!</h6>
    <h6><a href="offers.php" class="more">Offer Wall</a></h6>
  </div>
  <div class="col half float_r">
    <h2>Note From the admin</h2>
    <p>I've Recently Noticed alot of people have been requesting to know what the payment schedule is NOTE PAYMENTS ARE DETERMINED BY OUR ADVERTISERS Our Schedule is NET-30. This can change at any time</p>
    <ul class="templatemo_list">
      <li class="flow">Paypal is Preffered Method</li>
      <li class="flow">Amazon is also Supported</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <div class="cleaner h40"></div>
  <div class="cleaner"></div>
</div>
<!-- END of templatemo_main -->

<div id="templatemo_footer_wrapper">
    <div id="templatemo_footer">
    Copyright © 2014 <a href="index.php"><?php echo $title ?></a></div> <!-- END of templatemo_footer -->
</div> <!-- END of templatemo_footer_wrapper -->




<script type='text/javascript' src='js/logging.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an `'` in this line:

```
header ('Location: index.php);
```

It should be:

```
header ('Location: index.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed a quote `'` in `header ('Location: index.php)`. It should be :

```
<?php
include "system.php";
$usersystem = $_SESSION['username'];
$passw = $_SESSION['password'];
$query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$usersystem' AND password = '$passw'";
$autoexec= $mysqli->query($query);
$earnings = $autoexec['earnings'];
$completed = $autoexec['completed'];
if($_SESSION['loggedin']!=1){
    header ('Location: index.php');
                          //  --^
}
?>
```